# Convert and Transform JSON HTTP request to XML

Tags: json, xml, azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to create a Logic Apps workflow with three steps:

1. When HTTP Request is received (JSON)
2. Convert Json from request to XML
3. Save XML file to FTP

What I have done so far:

1. Add action "When HTTP Request is received"
2. Add Liquid to Convert JSON to XML 
   (but i don't see option JSON to XML...Only Tranform JSON to JSON, JSON to 
   TEXT, XML to JSON, XML to TEXT)
3. Add action "FTP - Create file"

I also created Integration Account and try to add map for mapping JSON to XML, but I can't find any examples/templates to do this...

Is it possible at all ? Maybe there is another way to convert between these two formats ?

Comment: As a workaround, you can use Azure functions to convert the json-xml (as *HTTP trigger*) then in your logic app simply call this and gets converted Reference:https://gordon.byers.me/azure/azure-functions-convert-json-to-xml-with-newtonsoft/

Comment: Do you need to just convert JSON->Xml or do you need to convert *and transform* JSON->Xml?

Comment: I need to save file in XML format on ftp, so i think, i need to convert and transform. I’m really new on this;)

Comment: @Jayendran thanks for link, but i don't know where use this code and how to call this..

Comment: @emerog try https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-call-azure-function-in-logic-apps/

Answer (score 3):

When you just want to **convert** a JSON payload to an XML file, without doing any transformation to the data, you can use the built-in xml() function of the Workflow Definition Language.

Detailed info in the docs: [Workflow Definition Language reference #xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#xml)

I've made a small test Logic App to demo your usecase. It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see I use the xml function on the triggerbody `@xml(triggerBody())` as an input for my FTP file content.

Remark: This will only work if your JSON message has a single rootnode. Otherwise the xml conversion will fail. You'll get this error:

> The provided value cannot be converted to XML: 'JSON root object has multiple properties. The root object must have a single property in order to create a valid XML document. Consider specifying a DeserializeRootElementName.

You can work around that by concatenating a rootnode to your JSON payload. The function then would look like: `@xml(json(concat('{\"rootnode\":',triggerBody(),'}')))`

Good luck testing this out. Let me know if you need more help with this.

Comment: thanks for a great explanation! Unfortunatelly i need to do some transormation to the data, but this is a good point to start :)

Comment: Once it's converted to XML you can use an XSLT map and the "Transform XML" action from the integration account to perform the necessary mappings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this:)